# Binding click event inside template with plain javascript as value in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, mouseclick-event

In this template, in first li element, I want to bind (click) event to store some values in localStorage. I am not getting any error but its not working. Iam trying to access this 'someStatus' in some other component using `localStorage.getItem('someStatus')` but Iam not getting the stored value on click. Please suggest me correct approach. Thank you.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Params, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from "@angular/router";
@Component({
selector: 'breadcrumb',
template: `<div id="crumbs">
<ul>
    <li routerLinkActive="active" (click)="localStorage.setItem('someStatus',false)"><a routerLink="/page1">Option 1</a></li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/page2" title="Summary">Option 2</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>`
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {constructor(  ) {  }  ngOnInit() {  }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context), you don't have access to global methods and objects (like `localStorage`) in the template:

> Template expressions cannot refer to anything in the global namespace
>   (except undefined). They can't refer to window or document. They can't
>   call console.log or Math.max. They are restricted to referencing
>   members of the expression context.

---

You can put the code in a method of the component:

```
public resetSomeStatus(): void {
    localStorage.setItem('someStatus', false);
}
```

and call that method in your click event:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" (click)="resetSomeStatus()">
```